# Mark C# field with a specific Input Json Property name

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net

In Asp.Net action **I want to receive as a parameter `FirstName`, but in json my clients send me `"first_name"`.** I would like to use FirstName but I don't want other users to change their calls from first_name to FirstName.

I tried **[JsonProperty("first_name")]**, but it doesn't work. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try `[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "first_name")]` instead

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. I'd *expect* `[JsonProperty("first_name")]` to be fine.

Comment: show some sample code. It should have worked.

Comment: Just tried [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "first_name")] - not working

Comment: You can always create your own attribute implementation performing a map between notations

Comment: when all else fails: `public string first_name {get { return FirstName; } set { FirstName = value; } } public bool ShouldSerializefirst_name() { return false; }`

Comment: Guys, my problem was in content-type I send from clients. Should be application/json. And then [JsonProperty("first_name")] works great!